# Sudo crontab not executing

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 and I set up my sudo crontab but the lines don't seem to be executing (e.g. my backup script is supposed to email me after completion but it never does, and its logs show it didn't run). My crontab (`sudo crontab -e`) looks like this:

```
0 8 * * * /usr/local/bin/cloudflare-ddns-update.sh
0 5 * * * /usr/local/bin/duplicacy-util -sd /home/rooday/.duplicacy-util -f mediabackup -a -m -q && curl -fsS --retry 5 -o /dev/null https://hc-ping.com/[removed the uuid for this post]
```

If check journalctl I see this for today (only showing relevant logs):

```
➜  ~ sudo journalctl -u cron.service
...
Jan 04 05:00:01 engager CRON[856196]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jan 04 05:00:01 engager CRON[856197]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/bin/duplicacy-util -sd /home/rooday/.duplicacy-util -f mediabackup -a -m -q && curl -fsS --retry 5 -o /dev/null https://hc-ping.com/[removed the uuid for this post])
Jan 04 05:00:01 engager CRON[856196]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
...
Jan 04 08:00:01 engager CRON[883807]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jan 04 08:00:01 engager CRON[883808]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/bin/cloudflare-ddns-update.sh)
Jan 04 08:00:11 engager CRON[883807]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
...
```

It's suspicious as the sessions are only open for a short time (granted the updating of DNS records could be accomplished in 10 seconds, but there's no chance the backup script finishes in under a second).

Furtheremore if I grep the syslog I get this (which has no reference to my backup or DNS updating):

```
➜  ~ cat /var/log/syslog | grep cron
Jan  4 00:17:01 engager CRON[812711]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jan  4 01:17:01 engager CRON[822094]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jan  4 01:32:02 engager CRON[824329]: (root) CMD (   test -x /etc/cron.daily/popularity-contest && /etc/cron.daily/popularity-contest --crond)
Jan  4 02:17:01 engager CRON[831325]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jan  4 03:17:01 engager CRON[840396]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jan  4 04:17:01 engager CRON[849724]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jan  4 05:17:01 engager CRON[858774]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jan  4 06:17:01 engager CRON[867977]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jan  4 06:25:01 engager CRON[869210]: (root) CMD (test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily ))
Jan  4 07:17:01 engager CRON[877115]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jan  4 07:30:01 engager CRON[879085]: (root) CMD ([ -x /etc/init.d/anacron ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d anacron start >/dev/null; fi)
Jan  4 07:34:00 engager systemd[1]: Started Run anacron jobs.
Jan  4 07:34:00 engager anacron[879690]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2021-01-04
Jan  4 07:34:00 engager anacron[879690]: Will run job `cron.daily' in 5 min.
Jan  4 07:34:00 engager anacron[879690]: Will run job `cron.weekly' in 10 min.
Jan  4 07:34:00 engager anacron[879690]: Jobs will be executed sequentially
Jan  4 07:39:00 engager anacron[879690]: Job `cron.daily' started
Jan  4 07:39:00 engager anacron[880491]: Updated timestamp for job `cron.daily' to 2021-01-04
Jan  4 07:39:02 engager anacron[879690]: Job `cron.daily' terminated
Jan  4 07:44:00 engager anacron[879690]: Job `cron.weekly' started
Jan  4 07:44:00 engager anacron[881356]: Updated timestamp for job `cron.weekly' to 2021-01-04
Jan  4 07:44:00 engager anacron[879690]: Job `cron.weekly' terminated
Jan  4 07:44:00 engager anacron[879690]: Normal exit (2 jobs run)
Jan  4 07:44:00 engager systemd[1]: anacron.service: Succeeded.
Jan  4 08:17:01 engager CRON[886527]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jan  4 08:30:01 engager CRON[888487]: (root) CMD ([ -x /etc/init.d/anacron ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d anacron start >/dev/null; fi)
Jan  4 08:34:50 engager systemd[1]: Started Run anacron jobs.
Jan  4 08:34:50 engager anacron[889199]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2021-01-04
Jan  4 08:34:50 engager anacron[889199]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
Jan  4 08:34:50 engager systemd[1]: anacron.service: Succeeded.
Jan  4 09:17:01 engager CRON[895646]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jan  4 09:30:01 engager CRON[897615]: (root) CMD ([ -x /etc/init.d/anacron ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d anacron start >/dev/null; fi)
Jan  4 09:34:20 engager systemd[1]: Started Run anacron jobs.
Jan  4 09:34:20 engager anacron[898342]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2021-01-04
Jan  4 09:34:20 engager anacron[898342]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
Jan  4 09:34:20 engager systemd[1]: anacron.service: Succeeded.
Jan  4 10:17:01 engager CRON[905160]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
```

I even set up Postfix so that I would receive emails after cronjobs (the warning about no MTA doesn't appear anymore), but I didn't receive those emails either. If I manually send a test email, or manually run any of the commands in my crontab, it all works fine. But they aren't running automatically, so is there something I'm missing here?

EDIT: After looking through some other posts I went to check the actual crontabs themselves, and I think the issue is that the user crontab for root isn't running. Because `/etc/crontab` includes these:

```
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
```

which seem to be running fine, but the crontab I edited ends up in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root`. Could it be an issue with cron not grabbing that file?

Comment: To avoid confusion: in `/etc/` there is the system-wide crontab. `/var/spool/cron/crontabs` contains crontabs for users, including root. With `sudo crontab -e` you edited the root's crontab. The system-wide one and the root's one are not the same. Cron e-mails the user if there's something wrong, but here the user is root. When you say "my crontab", are you aware it's "root's crontab"? Regular users change their crontabs with `crontab -e`.

Comment: Yep I'm intending to use root crontab here, and as for the email, I though that Postfix will always send to a specified email. As in the output from `sudo crontab -e` should be sent to the email I put in Postfix cfg with a from address of `root@rooday.com` (as that's the domain I specified in the cfg as well). Does cron only email if there are errors?

Comment: You said "my backup script is supposed to email me". If your script sends e-mails then it will do as scripted, even if run from cron. But only if it gets so far. If there's something wrong (e.g. the script cannot run at all) then cron itself will try to notify the user via e-mail. In my case this is totally local (I run `mail` to read) but I believe it one can set this up to send e-mails to the outside world. My points: (1) the address used by cron does not depend on the content of the script; (2) e-mails from this crontab go to root. So check root's e-mail, wherever it is.

Comment: Ah, the point about the backup script refers to a separate email service than Postfix for the crontab. The backup script itself is configured to send me an email (the backup binary includes this feature) and when I run the command from crontab manually (`/usr/local/bin/duplicacy-util -sd /home/rooday/.duplicacy-util -f mediabackup -a -m -q`) I receive the emails in my inbox as expected (this one isn't tied to the user who ran the script). But are you saying that cron will use whatever mail client to always mail {user}@{host}? Because in that case root@engager wouldn't go anywhere.

Comment: Try [this](https://serverfault.com/a/691047) maybe. Set up a simple job that prints something to stderr (e.g. `echo foo >&2`). If you receive a message from cron then you will know this is where errors (if any) from the jobs in question will go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel dumb, but the real issue was simply not having a newline at the end of the crontab. I saw that `/etc/crontab` ended with a line that only had `#`, so I copied that to my crontab and lo and behold, it worked! However it's pretty infuriating that an error like this wasn't caught automatically and failed silently instead (the logs acting as if the commands were being run). I thought that editing the crontab via `sudo crontab -e` would validate on exit, but apparently not.